# How do I add a video file to an event?

Tags: civievent

We are running CiviCRM version 4.7.24 on a Drupal 7 site. My client would like to add an MP4 video to an event page. I tried a simple upload of the video using the image button and I get the warning "Unknown image format/encoding" and the file is not uploaded. Is it possible to use video in CiviCRM event pages? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native CiviCRM -> try uploading your video to a third party service (like Vimeo or YouTube) and then embed the reference to it in an iFrame [where you describe/details of the Event].

Comment: I was able to embed a YouTube video by copying and pasting the embed code in the source code for the page. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly - great you got this working!

Comment: It seems like CiviCRM is blocking this embed code somehow. If I try this in a Drupal page, it works fine, but in the CiviEvent, the code never makes it to the actual event page even though the video preview is shown when editing the event.

Comment: Well - 5y ago it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but it may be as simple as adding mp4 as a safe file ending here: /civicrm/admin/options/safe_file_extension?reset=1

Comment: That did not work. Still get the same error message.